# MapView Callout onPress not triggering

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I've got a `MapView` from and I'm trying to render a location button, which is currently rendered in a callout and says "Find Me." The code is below.

The button displays nicely, but I can't get the onPress to work: when I click "Find Me", neither the "callout hello" or "button hello" log statements are logged, so nothing has been pressed (the button doesn't show any opacity on press either).

I've also tried rendering the button without the callout. It displays but still isn't pressed.

Help!

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { View, Button } from "react-native";
import { BLText } from "../components/StyledComponents";
import F8StyleSheet from "../components/F8StyleSheet";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const { Marker, Callout } = MapView;
import { getLocationAsync } from "../redux/actions/userActions";

FindMeButton = ({ onPress }) => {
  return (
    <Callout
      style={styles.locationButtonCallout}
      onPress={() => console.log("callout hello")}
    >
      <Button
        onPress={() => console.log("button hello")}
        title={"Find Me"}
        style={styles.locationButton}
      />
    </Callout>
  );
};

class MapScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Nearby Stations"
  };

  renderMarkers() {
    return (markers = Object.keys(this.props.stations).map(key => {
      const station = this.props.stations[key];
      return (marker = (
        <Marker
          key={key}
          // onPress={this.onMarkerPress.bind(this, station)}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: Number(station.location.lat),
            longitude: Number(station.location.lng)
          }}
        >
          <Callout
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("ListScreen");
              // this.props.navigation.navigate("StationDetail", {
              //   title: station.title
              // });
            }}
          >
            <BLText>{station.title}</BLText>
          </Callout>
        </Marker>
      ));
    }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log("rendering at region:", this.props.userLocation);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          region={this.props.userLocation}
          showsUserLocation={true}
        >
          {this.renderMarkers()}
          <FindMeButton onPress={this.props.getLocationAsync} />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stations: state.main.stations,
    userLocation: state.main.currentRegion
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getLocationAsync }
)(MapScreen);

const styles = F8StyleSheet.create({
  locationButtonCallout: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    opacity: 0.8,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
  },
  locationButton: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderRadius: 10,
    opacity: 0.8
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Callout` needs to be a sibling of `MapView`, not a child.

(updating with details by request, a year later)

Here's what `Callout` being a child means:

```
<MapView>
  <Callout/>
</MapView>
```

Here's what `Callout` being a sibling means:

```
<MapView/>
<Callout/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wanted to have it as a sibling of **MapView**, instead of **Marker**? The [docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#rendering-a-custom-marker-with-a-custom-callout) explicitly mentions sample codebase

```
import { Callout } from 'react-native-maps';

<Marker coordinate={marker.latlng}>
  <MyCustomMarkerView {...marker} />
  <Callout>
    <MyCustomCalloutView {...marker} />
  </Callout>
</Marker>
```

Moreover, I've tried your "solution", but it simply renders a button in the middle of the map. Instead, I guess most of us would like to have it rendered once user will click on the marker.

Based on https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2223, it looks like `Android` and `iOS` need 2 different event handlers.

`Android`

```
<Marker
  onCalloutPress={() => eventHandler()}
>
```

`iOS`

```
<Callout
  onPress={() => eventHandler()}
```